# This page isn’t working - localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, mamp

I am trying to install Magento 1.9.3 on my localhost.
I download ZIP -> unzip it -> put the entire folder in htdocs of MAMP. 
When i run the folder it shows an error -->

This page isn't working.

Above steps work well version 2.1.5.

I tried to change the php version of my system to 5.6 
Also the folder has permissions 777.

Kindly let me know what else can be done. I need help urgently.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rename the unzipped folder as 'magento' and in browser type : 'localhost/magento'.. Also recheck if the server is running properly..

Answer (score 0):

First Rename the folder as Magento, create a database name Magento then open browser type "localhost/Magento" its work

Answer (score 0):

First, enable error reporting from index.php.
You can do it using the following code.

> ini_set('display_errors', 1);
>
> ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
>
> error_reporting(E_ALL);

Check what's causing the issue and post it here.

Also, try to run it using IP address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I changed the Apache port to 80 (by clicking "Set Web..." button)  - problem solved.